# ALTER/CREATE Blocks when in transaction and uses loopback linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Using SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3, latest security packs applied.

The code below is a simplified/modified portion of a deploy script from SQL Compare. I changed a few names, but this code locks I when run it in SSMS.

The key things to note:

- The first ProcABC is required. If it's not there, everything runs fine.
- The linked server is a loopback server, but it's to an instance.  The data source for it is ".\SomeInstance". Linked server settings are:

  - Data Access: True
  - RPC & RPC Out: True
  - Use Remote Collation: True
  - Everything else is False.
- The problem only appears to be for a loopback server (even if I create it with my IP instead of using '.')

Symptoms are that the script just stops.  It's not blocked.  It just stops.

There is a second SPID that is blocked on the script SPID that is trying to call sys.sp_check_constbytable_rowset.

The only recovery is to kill the script SPID followed by killing the second SPID.  Kill the first only leave it in a KILLED/ROLLBACK state until the second is killed.  Killing only the second SPID causes a new one (also blocking and calling the same routine) to be generated.

I've tried changing all the SET settings.  Eliminating the enclosing transaction also eliminates the problem, but that's not a usable solution.

Any thoughts?

```
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, ARITHABORT, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL Read committed
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
PRINT N'Altering [dbo].[ProcABC]'
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcABC]
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON

END

GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
PRINT N'Altering [dbo].[FunctionABC]'
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FunctionABC] ()
RETURNS @ReturnTable TABLE
(
  ID   int,
  Name varchar(50)
)
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO @ReturnTable (ID, Name)
    SELECT ID, Name
    FROM LoopedBackLinkedServer.SomeDB.dbo.SomeTable

RETURN

END
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
DECLARE @Success AS BIT
SET @Success = 1
SET NOEXEC OFF
IF (@Success = 1) PRINT 'The database update succeeded'
ELSE BEGIN
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    PRINT 'The database update failed'
END
GO
```

Comment: I also just saw my first case where the second SPID was on sys.sp_tables_info_90_rowset_64, but was a variant where, instead of the CREATE of the dummy proc, there was a local refresh of a view.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm wondering if the linked server request is the second SPID and it's blocking on the original SPID because they're both accessing the same resource?  It's not running the code, only compiling, so maybe a schema lock?

Comment: Ah!  It looks like it's locking on sysschobjs.  Well.. bummer.  That's a protected table and I can't look at it.  But, it makes sense.